# Using a command-line option in a pytest skip-if condition

Tags: python, pytest

Long story short, I want to be able to skip some tests if the session is being run against our production API. The environment that the tests are run against is set with a command-line option.

I came across the idea of using the `pytest_namespace` to track global variables, so I set that up in my conftest.py file.

```
def pytest_namespace():
    return {'global_env': ''}
```

I take in the command line option and set various API urls (from a config.ini file) in a fixture in conftest.py.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def configInfo(pytestconfig):
    global data
    environment = pytestconfig.getoption('--ENV')
    print(environment)
    environment = str.lower(environment)

    pytest.global_env = environment

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini') # local config file
    configData = config['QA-CONFIG']
    if environment == 'qa':
            configData = config['QA-CONFIG']
    if environment == 'prod':
            configData = config['PROD-CONFIG']

(...)
```

Then I've got the test I want to skip, and it's decorated like so:

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(pytest.global_env in 'prod',
                reason="feature not in Prod yet")
```

However, whenever I run the tests against prod, they don't get skipped. I did some fiddling around, and found that:

a) the global_env variable is accessible through another fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def mod_header(request):
    log.info('\n-----\n| '+pytest.global_env+' |\n-----\n')
```

displays correctly in my logs

b) the global_env variable is accessible in a test, correctly logging the env.

c) `pytest_namespace` is deprecated

So, I'm assuming this has to do with when the skipif accesses that global_env vs. when the fixtures do in the test session. I also find it non-ideal to use a deprecated functionality.

My question is:

- how do I get a value from the pytest command line option into a skipif?
- Is there a better way to be trying this than the `pytest_namespace`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like true way to [Control skipping of tests according to command line option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option) is mark tests as *skip* dynamically:

1. add *option* using **pytest_addoption** hook like this:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--runslow", action="store_true", default=False, help="run slow tests"
    )
```

2. Use **pytest_collection_modifyitems** hook to add marker like this:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    if config.getoption("--runslow"):
        # --runslow given in cli: do not skip slow tests
        return
    skip_slow = pytest.mark.skip(reason="need --runslow option to run")
    for item in items:
        if "slow" in item.keywords:
            item.add_marker(skip_slow)
```

3. Add mark to you test:

```
@pytest.mark.slow
def test_func_slow():
    pass
```

If you want to use the data from the CLI in a test, for example, it`s *credentials*, enough to specify a [skip option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.config.Config.getoption) when retrieving them from the [pytestconfig](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytestconfig):

1. add *option* using **pytest_addoption** hook like this:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--credentials",
        action="store",
        default=None,
        help="credentials to ..."
    )
```

2. use **skip** option when get it from pytestconfig

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def super_secret_fixture(pytestconfig):
    credentials = pytestconfig.getoption('--credentials', skip=True)
    ...
```

3. use fixture as usual in you test:

```
def test_with_fixture(super_secret_fixture):
    ...
```

In this case you will got something like this it you not send `--credentials` option to CLI:

```
Skipped: no 'credentials' option found
```

It is better to use [_pytest.config.get_config](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/config.html#get_config) instead of deprecated **pytest.config** If you still wont to use [pytest.mark.skipif](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-mark-skipif) like this:

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(not _pytest.config.get_config().getoption('--credentials'), reason="--credentials was not specified")
```

Comment: Strange to me that `pytest`'s official answer to this is to implement a `--runslow` flag yourself.  I feel like it's inherent in the testing process that you are always going to have a handful long running, smoketest-y types of tests that you probably want to skip by default, would be nice if --runslow was built in.

Comment: What I find baffling is that, according to pytest's [historical notes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/historical-notes.html#string-conditions), users used to be able to do this in just one line as mentioned at the end of the answer using `pytest.mark.skipif(pytest.config.getoption(...))` and now they have to jump through a billion hoops and use the `modifyitems` hook. When they deprecated `pytest.config`, they should've just provided a similarly concise and officially supported (i.e. not `_pytest`-based) alternative for this common use case of having `skipif` depend on config options.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with putting global code in fixtures is that markers are evaluated before fixtures, so when `skipif` is evaluated, `configInfo` didn't run yet and `pytest.global_env` will be empty. I'd suggest to move the configuration code from the fixture to [`pytest_configure`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_configure) hook:

```
# conftest.py
import configparser
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--ENV')


def pytest_configure(config):
    environment = config.getoption('--ENV')
    pytest.global_env = environment
    ...
```

The configuration hook is guaranteed to execute before the tests are collected and the markers are evaluated.

> Is there a better way to be trying this than the `pytest_namespace`?

Some ways I know of:

1. Simply assign a module variable in `pytest_configure` (`pytest.foo = 'bar'`, like I did in the example above).
2. Use the `config` object as it is shared throughout the test session:

   ```
   def pytest_configure(config):
       config.foo = 'bar'

   @pytest.fixture
   def somefixture(pytestconfig):
       assert pytestconfig.foo == 'bar'

   def test_foo(pytestconfig):
       assert pytestconfig.foo == 'bar'
   ```

   Outside of the fixtures/tests, you can access the config via `pytest.config`, for example:

   ```
   @pytest.mark.skipif(pytest.config.foo == 'bar', reason='foo is bar')
   def test_baz():
       ...
   ```
3. Use [caching](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/cache.html); this has an additional feature of persisting data between the test runs:

   ```
   def pytest_configure(config):
       config.cache.set('foo', 'bar')

   @pytest.fixture
   def somefixture(pytestconfig):
       assert pytestconfig.cache.get('foo', None)

   def test_foo(pytestconfig):
       assert pytestconfig.cache.get('foo', None)

   @pytest.mark.skipif(pytest.config.cache.get('foo', None) == 'bar', reason='foo is bar')
   def test_baz():
       assert True
   ```

When using 1. or 2., make sure you don't unintentionally overwrite `pytest` stuff with your own data; prefixing your own variables with a unique name is a good idea. When using caching, you don't have this problem.

Comment: Sorry if this is a basic question, but is there a good reference for the order of execution for pytest? I figured that was the case, but I found it really hard to figure out what executed first.

Comment: I don't think this is a basic question; I actually never saw a full description of execution order of all framework parts. If in doubt, write a small test project that prints statements and analyze the output, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51685073/2650249) where I check the execution order of test class fixtures and methods.

Comment: **Brilliant.** Although you *do* explicitly note this caveat, it should be repeated that solutions 1. and 2. are fundamentally unsafe. However, 3. caches data across `py.test` invocations and hence is inapplicable for this use case. In short, there appears to be no safe means of resolving this deprecation in a global context (e.g., `@pytest.mark.skipif`). Since the [official documentation for this deprecation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#id3) is useless, this exhaustive answer is probably the best anyone can do. Clearly, *this should never have been deprecated.*