# How to resolve "PytestDeprecationWarning: pytest.config global is deprecated

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am testing a website called-https://huew.co

for that I am developing my framework.
In utils/create_driver, I wrote my code which will open the browser by user input like if user enter 'chrome' in terminal and env=local

Example: python -m pytest test/test_infilect.py --type=chrome --env=local
 then chrome browser should initialize and open the url which is provided.

but i am getting Error-
**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment**

**And Warning**:
PytestDeprecationWarning: the `pytest.config` global is deprecated.  Please use `request.config` or `pytest_configure` (if you'r
e a pytest plugin) instead.
    url = pytest.config.option.env.lower()

PytestDeprecationWarning: the `pytest.config` global is deprecated.  Please use `request.config` or `pytest_configure` (if you'r
e a pytest plugin) instead.
    browser_info = pytest.config.option.env.lower()

Help in regarding the same.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome,Firefox,Ie
import pytest

# @pytest.fixture
def get_browser_instance():

    browser_info = pytest.config.option.env.lower()

    url = pytest.config.option.env.lower()

    if browser_info == 'chrome':
        driver = Chrome('./browser_exe/chromedriver.exe')

    elif browser_info == 'firefox':
        driver = Firefox('./browser_exe/geckodriver.exe')

    elif browser_info == 'ie':
        driver = Ie('./browser_exe/IEDriverServer.exe')

    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(60)

    if url == 'local':
        driver.get('https://huew.co/')

    return driver
```

Test should run when I am entering command from pycharms terminal-
python -m pytest test/test_infilect.py --type=chrome --env=local

Comment: Your main problem is not the warning (as the q title says), it's just a deprication warning; the issue here is the UnboundLocalError exception for `driver` - it means you reference a variable which is not created. That means the if/else switch felt through without matching any of the options. Check the value of `browser_info` - does it match any of the 3 values you're checking.

Comment: I checked. driver = Chrome('./browser_exe/chromedriver.exe'), the relative path of chrome driver. but the error is still coming.

Comment: Hm, looking closer at the source, that's questionable to me - you are setting both `driver`, and `url` to the same value - `pytest.config.option.env`. At the end of the fixture you're checking is that value equal to "local" - to open the site you said you are testing; and in the same time, you expect its value to be one of the "chrome", "Firefox" or "ie" to open that browser.

Comment: **The deprecation warning is absolutely a problem,** albeit admittedly not the *main* problem in this case. To resolve this warning (and thus avoid future breakage), see [this authoritative answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51884507/2809027).

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass `request` as an argument to your fixture and replace references to `pytest.config` in your fixture body with `request.config`.