# pytest - skip classes based on their name - given from external file

Tags: python, pytest

I want to be able to predetermine which classes and tests should be tested by pytest by an external config file based on class name

All of our tests are under classes inheriting from same parent class

for example:
given a file in which TestClassA is marked as False :

```
   class TestClassA(parentTestClass):
        def test_TestClassA(self):
             ....
        def test_TestClassATwo(self):
            ....

   class TestClassB(parentTestClass):
       def test_TestClassB(self):
          ....
```

Only test_TestClassB should be executed and other should be marked as skipped

Is it possible with class decorators?

Comment: I wonder if some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883573/using-a-command-line-option-in-a-pytest-skip-if-condition) suggest some possible options?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) or [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) like this after you fetch the names from the external file:

```
locals()[f"test_{fetched_test_name}"]()
globals()[f"test_{fetched_test_name}"]()
```

Comment: The locals and globals indexes will get the function, and the codes above run the function that has been received.